# Decompostion into countably many nowhere dense compact sets

Tags: general-topology, locally-compact-groups

Let $A$ be a meagre subset of a locally compact abelian Polish group $G$. Then $A$ can be written as a countable union of nowhere dense subsets of $G$.

Is it always possible to write $A$ as a countable union of nowhere dense *compact* subsets of $G$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take an uncountable subset $S$ of the Cantor ternary set which does not contain any perfect set. Then $S$ is meager (even nowhere dense) in the real line but every compact subset of $S$ is countable so it cannot be covered by countably many compact subsets.

Comment: Interesting ! Do you have any reference for the existence of  an uncountable subset of the Cantor ternary set which does not contain any perfect set ?

Comment: You can take $S$ to be the intersection of a Bernstein set with the Cantor set. If you google about Bernstein sets, you should be able find many references for their construction.

Comment: No problem. You might also want to take a look at Oxtoby's measure and category. You can download the book here: http://math.rice.edu/~michael/teaching/426_Spr14/Banach_Mazur.pdf